# Is there a well defined default port number to be used as a Java RMI registry port

Tags: java, rmi, jmx

rmi.port is the port used for RMI communication. 
If its set as 0, a random available port is used at runtime. But the problem with this is that the RMI clients will not be able to
connect if the random port number assigned during runtime has a drop/reject
rule or does not have an allow rule in the firewall.

Instead, is there any well defined port number which can be configured to let administrators define a allow/grant firewall rule.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `rmi.port`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any well defined port number which can be configured to let administrators define a allow/grant firewall rule

Yes, there is [`java.rmi.registry.Registry.REGISTRY_PORT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/rmi/registry/Registry.html#REGISTRY_PORT), whose value is [1099](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.rmi.registry.Registry.REGISTRY_PORT), which has been registered with [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) since at least 1996.